# How to paste subset of columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I paste together a dynamic subset of columns from a data.frame using dplyr?

If I have a following function:

```
d = data.frame(a = 1:5, b=2:6, c=3:7)

fun = function(d, colnames){

    d$f = Reduce(function(x,y)paste(x,y,sep='_'), d[,colnames])

    return(d)
}

fun(d, c('a','b'))

fun(d, c('b','c'))

fun(d, c('a','b','c'))
```

How do I rewrite the function using dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a version of your function using `dplyr` and `rlang`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

fun = function(d,a,b){
  a.var <- enquo(a)
  b.var <- enquo(b)
  d %>% mutate(f = paste(!!a.var,!!b.var, sep="_"))
}

fun(d,a,b)
```

## Update

```
fun = function(d,...){
  #browser()
  vars  <- quos(...)
  d %>% mutate(f = paste(!!!vars, sep="_"))
}

fun(d,a)
fun(d,c,a)
fun(d,a,b,c)
```

Comment: Thank  you for the answer!
How would I do this if I have a variable number of columns? - I have edited the example

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example:

```
> library(dplyr)    
> d = data.frame(a = 1:5, b=2:6, c=3:7)
> d <- d %>% mutate(f = paste(a,b,sep='_'))
> d
  a b c   f
1 1 2 3 1_2
2 2 3 4 2_3
3 3 4 5 3_4
4 4 5 6 4_5
5 5 6 7 5_6
```

EDIT:

After your edit, this will work for you:

```
> library(dplyr)
> d = data.frame(a = 1:5, b=2:6, c=3:7)
> colnames <- c("a", "c")
> d <- d %>% mutate(f = paste(!!as.name(colnames[1]),!!as.name(colnames[2]),sep='_'))     
> d
  a b c   f
1 1 2 3 1_3
2 2 3 4 2_4
3 3 4 5 3_5
4 4 5 6 4_6
5 5 6 7 5_7
```

Comment: How can I specify the columns dynamically?

Comment: @user680111 could you explain that in your case? Maybe update/edit your question with the output you want? Not sure what you want right now, sorry.

Comment: @user680111 I saw your edit and changed my answer. I think this is what you mean?

Comment: @user680111 If you are going to ask a new question every time someone answers your current question, please open a new topic. Or specify your question in the first post, this way we keep editing..

Comment: "How do I paste together a **dynamic subset** of columns from a data.frame using dplyr" 
Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, use `tidyr::unite`!

It allows dynamic selection of columns, and has options for excluding missing values (`NA`) and keeping or dropping input variables.

```r
d = data.frame(a = 1:5, b=2:6, c=3:7)

d |>
  tidyr::unite("new_col", a:c, remove = FALSE)
#>   new_col a b c
#> 1   1_2_3 1 2 3
#> 2   2_3_4 2 3 4
#> 3   3_4_5 3 4 5
#> 4   4_5_6 4 5 6
#> 5   5_6_7 5 6 7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>